# Best method for calling function parameters in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working with some slightly tricky code. Basically, I'm trying to pull a `<script>` tag from around 10 pages on a site I'm developing for. This code's syntax is incorrect, as you cannot use brackets in function parameters, but it's the essence of what I'm trying to perform:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var resp = new Array();
var htmlDoc = new Array();
var findScripts = new Array();
var searchScripts = new Array();
var scriptContent = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
    resp[i] = prodDetails[i].responseText;
    htmlDoc[i] = parser.parseFromString(resp[i],"text/html");
    findScripts[i] = htmlDoc[i].body.querySelectorAll('script');
    searchScripts[i] = Array.prototype.filter.call(findScripts[i], function (findScripts[i]) {
        return RegExp('var prodInfo = ').test(findScripts[i].textContent);
    });
    scriptContent[i] = searchScripts[i].innerText;
}
```

**Further, possibly unneeded details:**

I'm using the following code to grab each page:

```
var text = "";
var prodDetails = new Array();
var amt = document.querySelectorAll('[id="product-details"]').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
        prodDetails[i] = $.get(itemPages[i].href, {}, function (results) {
        });
    }
```

Following this, I am then parsing the information so that the tag can be pulled through simple JavaScript commands:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var resp = new Array();
var htmlDoc = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
    resp[i] = prodDetails[i].responseText;
    htmlDoc[i] = parser.parseFromString(resp[i],"text/html");
}
```

This works for accessing each page's DOM individually by calling `htmlDoc[0]` through `htmlDoc[9]`, but there are around 8 `<script>` tags on each of the pages. The one that I'm looking for contains specific text in its innerHTML. I can find the one I'm looking for using:

```
var findScripts = htmlDoc[0].body.querySelectorAll('script');
var searchScripts = Array.prototype.filter.call(findScripts, function (findScripts) {
    return RegExp('var prodInfo = ').test(findScripts.textContent);
});
var scriptContent = searchScripts[0].innerText;
```

This code works great when ran on its own, but this means manually running each time changing the index value of `htmlDoc`, and I'm looking for more of an "all at once" solution.

I'm not opposed to using jQuery in this, but I am mostly unfamiliar with it. If there is a more powerful jQuery-based solution, I will take that as well. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a JavaScript taskrunner, like Gulp, Grunt or Webpack, to import and combine these scripts into a single payload, which is then just included on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than assigning to someArr[i] and someOtherArr[i] over and over, I suggest just pushing to the arrays in question instead, the code will look a lot cleaner. Also, you can use `forEach` for better abstraction, to avoid manual iteration, and to avoid the problems with `i` hoisting:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const responseTexts = [];
const htmlDocs = [];
const findScripts = [];
const filteredScripts = [];
const scriptContent = [];

prodDetails.forEach((response) => {
  const responseText = response.responseText;
  const newDoc = parser.parseFromString(responseText,"text/html");
  const thisDocScripts = newDoc.querySelectorAll('script');
  const thisDocFilteredScripts = [...thisDocScripts]
    .filter(oneScript => oneScript.textContent.includes('const prodInfo = '));
  const thisDocScriptsContent = thisDocFilteredScripts.map(scr => scr.textContent);

  responseTexts.push(responseText);
  htmlDocs.push(newDoc);
  findScripts.push(thisDocScripts);
  filteredScripts.push(thisDocFilteredScripts);
  scriptContent.push(thisDocScriptsContent);
});
```

Abstraction is wonderful.

Do you really need all of those variables saved in arrays, though?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! This solution ended up working perfectly for me. I do have a question about it though, as I'm a little perplexed, and would rather learn from this rather than just roll with the solution.

I do not see "oneScript" defined anywhere, however this works perfectly for filtering the text from thisDocFilteredScripts. How does this work?

Also to answer your question, I'm not so sure that I need all of it saved in arrays, but it did help me to find each individual component via index number in troubleshooting.

Comment: @notdan It's just an argument - `filter` accepts a function as its argument, and `oneScript` is an argument of that function. (you can use any string as an argument, preferably one that hasn't been previously defined) Look up arrow functions.